# AsciiDoctor: How can I add custom xmlns'

Tags: asciidoctor

How can I add a custom `xmlns` in the output when I convert an asciidoc file with AsciiDoctor?

I'd like to add `xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"` in the top  `book` tag.

The current implementation seems to generate:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?asciidoc-toc?>
<?asciidoc-numbered?>
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0" xml:lang="en">
<info>
<title>title</title>
</info>
</book>
```

from this:

```
= title
:lang: en
```

When I run:

```sh
$ asciidoctor -b docbook5 -d book -o out.xml source.txt
```

There is a [built-in attribute `xmlns`](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#builtin-attributes), but it seems to be for docbook 4.5.

The reason I want to use XInclude is to include some xml files from [Docinfo files](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file) and [Passthrough Blocks](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#pass-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of research inside the asciidoctor code it quickly became clear that the part you'd like to modify is fairly static.
See [asciidoctor/converter/docbook5.rb Line 44](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/blob/v2.0.12/lib/asciidoctor/converter/docbook5.rb#L44) for more info.

The best approach is to create a postprocessor extension which modifies the output. The example below is just to show a possible implementation.

Create a file with the following content and call it `docbook_postprocessor.rb`.

```rb
class Docbook5XiPostprocessor < Asciidoctor::Extensions::Postprocessor
  def process document, output
    if document.basebackend? 'docbook'
      input_regex = %r{^(<.*xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink") (version="5.0".*>)}
      replacement = %(\\1 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" \\2)
      output = output.sub(input_regex, replacement)
    end
    output
  end
end

Asciidoctor::Extensions.register do
  postprocessor Docbook5XiPostprocessor
end
```

Note: The above extension is for the sake of brevity placed in the same directory as the asciidoctor source file called `source.adoc`.

The run the asciidoctor command with the `-r ./docbook_postprocessor.rb` parameters.

```sh
$ asciidoctor -r ./docbook_postprocessor.rb -b docbook5 -d book -o - source.adoc  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?asciidoc-toc?>
<?asciidoc-numbered?>
<book
  xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
  xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  version="5.0"
  xml:lang="en">
<info>
<title>test</title>
<date>2020-12-19</date>
</info>
</book>
```

<sup>* Above output has been slightly reformatted to eliminate the scrollbar</sup>

Creating ruby `gem` with the above code for easier distribution is a task left to the reader.